# Is "Shinya" gender-neutral name? Would it be too weird as female name?

Tags: names, gender

I'm creating a female character. I really like that name but afraid that it's too weird for a woman, as every character or person I seen with that name were male.

Comment: I personally don't think so, I've never seen "Shinya" as female's name in real life, at least past ~30 years.

Comment: や is typically a male name "suffix" from what I've heard.  That being said, I can't say for certain it's ***not*** used in female names.  Besides, Shinya busted the curve in Ted's *Robin 101* course, so maybe steer clear of that.

Answer (score 2):

It may be not *too* weird, but it would sound weird as a female name. I guess it is not impossible for some strange parents to give such (male) names to girls.

You can search keywords like '男女兼用 名前' to get the idea of which names can be used for boys and girls (like [1](https://namedic.jp/names/unisex/), [2](https://pon-navi.net/nazuke/popular/chuuseiteki-namae), [3](https://ranking.goo.ne.jp/column/6257/ranking/52366/))

---

'Ya' in *Shinya* is most likely to be written as 也, which indicates a male name most of the time. [This site](https://b-name.jp/%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/f/%E3%82%84/?t=s&mode=3) lists 亜也 as a female name, though. (あや is a common female name, but the particular kanji rendering is not.)